# SQL Query: CREATE a table with rows divided by month/year and COUNT the number of values WHERE '01/month/year' IS BETWEEN two date-columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, between

this is my first question here.

I have a problem in creating a complex query to group values based on if the  first day of month/year falls in between two date columns.

here is an example of the table I have:

| USER_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/07/2020 | 31/07/2020 |
| A | 05/06/2020 | 03/07/2020 |
| A | 08/05/2020 | 05/06/2020 |
| A | 10/04/2020 | 08/05/2020 |
| B | 13/02/2020 | 12/03/2020 |
| B | 16/01/2020 | 13/02/2020 |
| C | 22/05/2020 | 19/06/2020 |
| C | 24/04/2020 | 22/05/2020 |
| D | 25/09/2020 | 23/10/2020 |
| D | 28/08/2020 | 25/09/2020 |
| D | 31/07/2020 | 28/08/2020 |
| D | 03/07/2020 | 31/07/2020 |
| D | 05/06/2020 | 03/07/2020 |
| E | 25/11/2020 | 23/12/2020 |
| E | 28/10/2020 | 25/11/2020 |
| E | 30/09/2020 | 28/10/2020 |
| F | 14/2/2020 | 13/3/2020 |
| F | 17/1/2020 | 14/2/2020 |
| F | 20/12/2019 | 17/1/2020 |
| F | 22/11/2019 | 20/12/2019 |
| G | 7/11/2020 | 5/12/2020 |
| G | 10/10/2020 | 7/11/2020 |

and I wish to have something like that:

| YEAR | MONTH | COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 11 | 0 |
| 2019 | 12 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020 | 4 | 0 |
| 2020 | 5 | 2 |
| 2020 | 6 | 2 |
| 2020 | 7 | 2 |
| 2020 | 8 | 1 |
| 2020 | 9 | 1 |
| 2020 | 10 | 2 |
| 2020 | 11 | 2 |
| 2020 | 12 | 2 |

For instance, in Feb 2020 user "B" and user "F" had a range of dates that included the date 01/Feb/2020 (the condition is true for:

| USER_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 16/01/2020 | 13/02/2020 |

and for:

| USER_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | 17/1/2020 | 14/2/2020 |

...so the count will be 2.

Do you know any way to do it in SQL (or Ruby)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH m AS
( SELECT generate_series(min(date_trunc('month', start_date)), max(end_date), '1 month') :: date AS month
    FROM my_table AS t
)
SELECT to_char(m.month, 'YYYY') AS year
     , to_char(m.month, 'MM') AS month
     , count(DISTINCT t.user_id) AS "count(distinct user_id)"
  FROM my_table AS t
 RIGHT JOIN m
    ON daterange(t.start_date, t.end_date) @> m.month
 GROUP BY m.month
 ORDER BY m.month
```

The first query `"m"` calculates the list of months that cover the `start_date` and `end_date` of `my_table`.

The second query join `my_table` with the resulting table `"m"` in order to select all the users whose interval `daterange(start_date, end_date)` contains the 1st day of the month (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)).

Then the rows are grouped by `m.month` and the number of distinct user_id per month is calculated with the `count(DISTINCT user_id)` aggregate function (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)).

Finally the `RIGHT JOIN` clause allows to select the months with no corresponding `user_id` in `my_table` (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)).

See the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9e64953b022db025caf34eaf382514d7).